# How to add a WAI-compliant label to a Symfony form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, wai-aria

WAI validation requires label with for attribute associated with every form inputs.

How can I add label on form from this code?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Nom, Prénom', ),
         ))
    ;
}
```

Things like this do not work:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom', 'text', array(
           'label' => 'whatever',
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Nom, Prénom', ),
         ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: When you say *does not work* what exactly is not working? I use the `label` attribute all the time and it works just fine for me. Is there anything specific you are looking for?

Comment: How do you render form in template?

Comment: the label html is not generated

Comment: {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST'}) }} {{ form_widget(form.nom) }}{{ form_end(form) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `{{ form_label(form.nom) }}` separately if you are not rendering the whole form.

Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-basics)

Do something like this in your code:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST'}) }} 
{{ form_label(form.nom) }}
{{ form_widget(form.nom) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and it should work.